# No Android Kit in Qt 5.2 for Android

Tags: android, c++, linux, qt

My OS is Debian Wheezy, I downloaded and installed the [Qt 5.2.0 for Android (Linux 64-bit, 488 MB)](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.0/qt-linux-opensource-5.2.0-android-x86_64-offline.run.mirrorlist) installer.

This installer, I assume, is meant to work out of the box. When I create a new project, however, there are no Android Kits, only the Desktop kit. This is how the dialog looks like:

[image]

Has anyone else had the same problem? How did you solve it?

Comment: Check what version of qmake is used using command: qmake -query. You'll see where it's located, after that go to QtCreator and in Options->Qt Versions create new version and insert path with qmake for Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out what the problem was, after some more searching - I hadn't installed the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html). After installing them (into `/opt/`), I needed to select their paths in this dialog:

[image]

I have the Android Kits now:

[image]